# Can't track tag badges properly

Tags: bug, badges

When I go to my profile's summary and click on the gear next to "Next tag badge", it doesn't allow me to choose whether to track a tag badge or  regular one. It assumes regular and as such it is kinda hard for me to track my progress in various tags. I just noticed this today.

Comment: It's a bug related to the [new Activity page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372049/644344). It has been reported.

Comment: It seems to have been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can track both tag and normal badges, it's just a little further on the right for normal and on the left for tags  :

[image: Tag badges]

Remember to switch to track tag badges instead of privilege, if applicable (you've got quite a good chunk of points so I don't know if you've earned all privileges). Now, if you don't see the box on the right, then you (don't) have some interesting things to check :).

---

*N.B. : There's an hinderance of the utmost importance, even more than tracking badges : Why are the cog to track privileges or badges and the one to choose tag badges not perfectly aligned on the horizontal axis? Kidding of course!*

Comment: Tried that, doesn't work. I still see only regular badge progress

Comment: @TheSquare-cubelaw Ack, there must be something different from me. Do you look at the site from a phone? Or from a specific browser? Used firefox for the screenshot.